# How to replace a fragment in a TabLayout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a TabLayout with three tabs, each Tab had its own fragment (Deferent classes and deferent type of fragments.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            BooksFragment tabBooks = new BooksFragment();
            return tabBooks;
        case 1:
            NavigationFragment tabNav = new NavigationFragment();
            return tabNav;
        case 2:
            SearchFragment tabSearch = new SearchFragment();
            return tabSearch;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

In tabBooks i have a table with books and when someone clicks a book i need to open the chapters. (This is working, getting the chapters form the web and populating a table in the Chapter Fragment).
For that i have a chapter fragment.

I'm probably doing something very wrong here: (In BooksFragment - onListItemClick):

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, new ChapterFragment()).commit();
```

fm is the FragmentManager:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

The result i am getting is a fragment on top of all the other fragments and it stays on top of everything when i am switching tabs.

I know this is wrong and this way i don't have a back button functionality also, the back button will go back to the home screen, not the prev state (fragment) i was in.

I just can't find the solution for that.

Im using

> FragmentPagerAdapter

But i'm guessing that this is not the issue, the issue is with the

> R.id.main_layout

in the fm.beginTransaction call or that i am using it in FragmentManager. but i can't seem to find the right way to do that

Again, looking for a way to change fragment in a TabLayout just for the specific Tab.

2. In the same subject, How do i then go back to the first Fragment when someone is clicking the back button or pressing the back button i have in my ToolBar (Again, in the same tab).

I'm sitting on this specific action for 2 days now and can't find the solution.

The page Adapter I'm using in MainActivity (My only activity):

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int mNumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position){
    switch (position){
        case 0:
            BooksFragment tabBooks = new BooksFragment();
            return tabBooks;
        case 1:
            NavigationFragment tabNav = new NavigationFragment();
            return tabNav;
        case 2:
            SearchFragment tabSearch = new SearchFragment();
            return tabSearch;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

}

Main Activity:

```
public ViewPager pager;
PagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("ספרים"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.navigation_title));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText(R.string.search_title));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    adapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab){
            pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab){}
    });
}
```

Book Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    switch (displayType) {
        case CATEGORIES:
            Category cat = (Category) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            books = cat.getBooks();
            updateDisplay(ItemType.BOOKS);
            displayType = ItemType.BOOKS;
            break;
        case BOOKS:
            Book book = (Book) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, new ChapterFragment()).commit();
            break;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You want to replace `tabFragment` with `chapterFragment` with other two tabs still intact?

Comment: Can you post your class code extending`FragmentPagerAdapter` and also the code related to `Viewpager` setup.

Comment: I've updated will all the relevant code i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use childFragmentManager like below instead of supportFragmentManager.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    switch (displayType) {
        case CATEGORIES:
            Category cat = (Category) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            books = cat.getBooks();
            updateDisplay(ItemType.BOOKS);
            displayType = ItemType.BOOKS;
            break;
        case BOOKS:
            Book book = (Book) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //change this
            //FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_layout, new ChapterFragment()).commit();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: 10x, This is the right direction, I'm using TabPageIndicator instead. following the instruction solved me backPress also and everything is working except that i lost my ToolBar, but i will fix that... but this is the right answer, 10x